# Booting from thumb on Windows 8

Tags: installation, windows-8

I'm using a 4Gig USB thumbdrive to create a bootable USB 
stick on Windows to Install Ubuntu 12.10. I've been using this page for step by step instructions, http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

I had no problems with the guide and now have the USB thumb set up, after I set the USB thumb drive as first priority in the boot order I save the settings and windows continues to load even though I selected boot from USB before the Hard drive.

The thumb drive stays plugged in the entire time, this is my second attempt at trying Linux. I first tried installing it from Windows but because I have an UEFI motherboard it is not compatible. I would have already tried the CD/DVD method but I do not have any, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What machine is it? If Secure Boot (shudder) is enabled, you need to disable it before the computer will boot Linux.

Comment: It was enabled, after a quick search on what "Secure Boot" is I disabled it, however I still can not boot from the thumb drive. Is this what the drive is suppose to look like? http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=23gzex0&s=6

Answer (score 0):

Try to stick restore as described [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/put-ubuntu-10-04-on-flash-drive-using-windows/)

Comment: I downloaded the Torrent from that link, after the Torrent was done I downloaded the USB installer. From the USB installer I selected Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop, then I selected the 11.10 Desktop ISO from the torrent. After that I selected my formatted (fat32) 4gb USB thumb drive, making sure I selected the right drive I then clicked create. After the program complete successfully

Comment: I navigated to the USB thumb drive on my computer, I opened it up and ran "wubi". After opening "wubi" I selected "Demo and full installation" after that choosing to "reboot now" from the next page. However, before doing any of this I made sure my boot order was "USB,CD/DVD, Hard-drive" in my bios, I also double  checked to make sure secure boot was still disabled. When all this was said and done the installer prompted me to restart and I did, but upon doing so I booted back into windows.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with that order or selection?